# Ocultar función para conectar PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenemos unos desarrollos en `PHP` conectados a una base de datos `MySQL`, los datos de conexión ya están en un archivo .config fuera del acceso público y se cargan con include.

La inquietud del cliente es que alguien ajeno a su equipo de trabajo con acceso al servidor (soporte técnico externo, por ejemplo) pueda buscar el texto `mysql_connect(` y a partir de ahí moverse entre archivos para obtener el usuario y la contraseña.

El cliente espera una solución de seguridad por ocultación, encriptar archivos o que no aparezcan las funciones al momento de realizar una búsqueda. ¿Hay alguna alternativa que funcione y no signifique una mala práctica?

El escenario es que la persona ya esté dentro del servidor y le interesen las credenciales para la base de datos.

Comment: quiza con esto http://teampasswordmanager.com/docs/encrypt-db-parameters/

Comment: @jasilva ¡Gracias por la sugerencia! Aunque para este caso el cliente espera una solución en la cual no se tenga que instalar una herramienta comprada en el server, de ahí surgió la pregunta (¿la edito para destacar también este punto?).

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de servidor es? Si es UNIX/Linux con que cambies el acceso del directorio que contiene el config, debería ser suficiente. ¿no?

Comment: De que tipo de acceso hablas cunado te referís a que alguien externo va a acceder al servidor??  Si me decís que ese soporte externo se va a conectar por ftp por ejemplo si hay algunas formas.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro los desarrollos están sobre wampserver 2.2

Comment: Me imagino que @AlvaroMontoro se refiere a los permisos de usuario, algo que parece muy conveniente ya que solo un segmento de usuarios podrán tener acceso a la carpeta donde esta la conexión.

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas sí, me refería a eso. Pero OP usa WAMP y no sé si en Windows se puede hacer algo así.

Comment: Primero quiero aclarar que no soy un experto, pero he visto que es posible hacerlo. Los permisos que se le puede dar una carpeta en Windows son bastante similares a GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma buena de hacerlo, es obligar a la base de datos, a que solo se pueda **conectar desde un Host concreto**, de esta manera, no podrá conectarse a pesar de que conozca las credenciales nada mas que desde ese propio equipo. En el caso de mysql ,tambien lo puedes hacer con **un certificado SSL**, de esta manera tendría que tener dicho certificado instalado además (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/secure-connections.html).

Ten en cuenta que cualquier medida de ocultación, (security obscurity - https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seguridad_por_oscuridad), el servidor PHP va tener que desocultarla, y siempre que tenga acceso, va poder hacer la acción inversa, si ofuscas esa parte, la podrá desofuscar llevandose el archivo.

```
  <?php
// Este archivo es protegido por la ley del derechos de propiedad literaria. La ingenieria inversa de este codigo se prohibe estrictamente.
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('
s7fjsrFXSE3OyFdQKUssykxMykm1VrC34+UCigMA
')));
?>
```

Por ejemplo eso hace un

```
<? echo $variable; ?>
```

Pero creo que cualquiera puede reversearlo.

Si el que se conecta es un sysadmin, la ocultación no tiene sentido, pero sino también podrías eliminar los derechos de lectura de esa carpeta de cualquier usuario que no sea el que utiliza tu servidor apache/nginx

Answer (score 1):

Serviría un daemon que actualice las credenciales de logueo cada x tiempo?? Claro que para eso tendrían que poner un control para tener el control del proceso.

Answer (score 1):

En general, no es deseable capturar contraseñas en el código fuente, esto además de seguridad, ayuda con la portabilidad de la aplicación, por ejemplo no necesitas dar la contraseña de la base de producción a desarrolladores, y pueden ellos trabajar con su propia instancia, apuntando a una base de pruebas.

La manera más eficiente es poner usuario, contraseña, puerto, host, en **variables de entorno**, y para importarlas en la aplicación, definirlas como constantes:

```
<?php
// config/environment.php
define('DB_PASS', filter_var($_SERVER['db_password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
define('DB_USER', filter_var($_SERVER['db_username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
define('DB_HOST', filter_var($_SERVER['db_hostname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
define('DB_PORT', filter_var($_SERVER['db_port'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
```

De este modo, si aún utilizas la extensión mysql, tu función de conexión podría consumir estas constantes así:

```
$link=mysql_connect(DB_HOST . ':' . DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASS, FALSE, $client_flags);
```

Entonces la seguridad residiría en quién y cómo puede obtener acceso a las variables de entorno.

Por ejemplo con PHP-FPM, [supongamos que usamos el pool predeterminado](http://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2015/12/13/symfony-nginx-environment-variables-php-fpm/) `[www]`, por ejemplo en `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`:

```
env[DB_USER] = "user"
env[DB_PASS] = "pass"
```

Y dependiendo del servidor, la aplicación y el entorno, podría haber opciones más flexibles o más complejas. Pero la esencia es esta: [no pongas datos confidenciales en el código fuente sino que se carguen desde el entorno](https://12factor.net/es/config). Los ejemplos que te proporciono son de la refactorización de una aplicación legacy en PHP y hasta el momento siguen funcionando.

Para una aplicación usando Apache, puedes usar las directivas SetEnv en la configuración del host sobre el que corre la aplicación, de esa manera solo están disponibles a PHP al ser invocado por Apache.

```
SetEnv DB_USER usuario
SetEnv DB_PASS contraseña
```

No obstante como señala @leonbloy objetando mi primer respuesta, y luego cayendo en el mismo dilema en la suya, si otros tienen acceso al servidor con suficientes privilegios, pueden leer cualquier archivo donde sea que lo pongas. En ese caso lo único viable es cambiar las contraseñas cada vez que entra alguien externo, igualito que se cambian cuando sale un empleado que tenía acceso a credenciales privilegiadas.

Comment: "Pero la esencia es esta: no pongas datos confidenciales en el código fuente sino que se carguen desde el entorno." No creo que ese consejo tenga que ver con seguridad sino con flexibilidad para correr mismo código en distintos ambientes. Las variables de entorno son (muy) visibles.

Comment: Depende de para quién, desde la web, solo que dejes un archivo con la función `phpinfo()` colgando por ahí. Si tus usuarios tienen acceso a ver las variables de entorno, entonces sí, estás perdido y ninguna medida servirá para que no vean el código fuente. Ahora, **no se trata de poner variables de entorno _globales_, sino específicas al proceso de PHP que sirve la aplicación.** Por eso la referencia a PHP FPM para que solo ese pool tenga acceso a esas variables, no todos.

Comment: No veo la diferencia (y, repito, el enlace que pones no habla de seguridad en ningún momento). Si alguien se loguea en el server (la inquietud original) como root o al menos como el usuario que sirve la aplicación, da lo mismo que pueda leer un archivo 'config.php' o el archivo donde se setean esas variables de ambiente (o, peor, loguearse como el usuario y ejecutar un `printenv `)

Comment: De nuevo planteas otro escenario que no es el que se presenta con esta propuesta, ya que no estamos hablando de variables de entorno, disponibles para todos los procesos de un usuario, sino de variables que se pasan a solamente un proceso, independientemente del proceso. Eso no se puede obtener tan fácilmente al _loguearse_ (sic) como el usuario. Tendrían que conocer mucho más de la configuración de tu servidor para hacerlo, y eso no es lo mismo que poner la contraseña en el código fuente o un archivo de credenciales junto al código. No poder reconocer las diferencias sutiles ya es cosa tuya.

Answer (score 1):

> La inquietud del cliente es que alguien ajeno a su equipo de trabajo con acceso al servidor (soporte técnico externo, por ejemplo) pueda buscar el texto mysql_connect( y a partir de ahí moverse entre archivos para obtener el usuario y la contraseña.

Hablando en general, no es una inquietud razonable. Lo razonable, en el 99% de los casos, es dar por supuesto que "**si alguien tiene acceso al servidor, y puede asumir la identidad del usuario con que corre la aplicación, entonces puede hacer todo lo que puede hacer la aplicación**" (conectarse a la DB entre otras cosas), y no pretender rebelarse contra ese supuesto sino pensar tu esquema de seguridad en base a él.

Lo aconsejable entonces es limitarse a garantizar que la conexión se pueda establecer solo desde cierta(s) IP(s) y que los archivos donde se almacenan las claves son solo legibles por el usuario que corre la aplicación. Si hay otros usuarios que entran al servidor por tareas de mantenimiento, o bien no deberían poder acceder con los permisos de ese usuario, o bien hay que tener claro (resignarse) a que podrán conectarse a la DB.

El resto, es o bien "seguridad mediante oscuridad" (en general no recomendable) o bien soluciones demasiado complejas que *muy* raramente se justifican.

Si no estás convencido, más información en inglés [aquí](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48590/reasonable-way-to-store-encrypted-passwords-in-a-webapps-database-linux).

Comment: ¿Y no es lo mismo que objetabas contra mi respuesta? Te cito: _**"Si alguien se loguea en el server ... como root o al menos como el usuario que sirve la aplicación, da lo mismo que pueda leer un archivo 'config.php' o el archivo donde se setean esas variables...**_" Da lo mismo que el archivo solo lo pueda leer "el usuario que corre la aplicación", si tu le das acceso a otros como "root" o administrador, también podrían editar los archivos de PHP a manera de imprimir en pantalla la contraseña, extraer el certificado de conexión de MySQL o decodificar una función ofuscada con base 64, etcétera

Comment: Por supuesto que es lo mismo. Es precisamente lo que te objeté: que no se gana nada (respecto a la seguridad) con poner la clave en variables de ambiente, en lugar de en un archivo php.

Comment: Es distinto, no obstante estoy de acuerdo con tu argumentación de que si tienen acceso de administrador, tarde o temprano tendrían acceso a cualquier archivo o entorno. Sin embargo poner tus contraseñas en archivos, facilita que están se propaguen, por ejemplo, a repositorios de control de versiones, no así con variables de entorno. Sin embargo estoy de acuerdo con tu objeción en general y por eso voté por tu respuesta y edité la mía en concordancia.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer todo eso, poner el usuario encriptado, host, clave encriptados en un archivo fuera del acceso púbico, revisar los permisos. luego crear una librería php que desencripte los datos y haga la conexion, que te provea una una funcion tipo obtener_conexion_bd()
luego ofuscas esa librería y la encriptas, y la usas con 99% de tranquilidad en el resto del código

http://www.zend.com/
http://www.ioncube.com/
http://www.protegerphp.info/